# Transfer of data from server to other objects

Tags: c++, server, winsock

I have a [Winsock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545(v=vs.85).aspx) `Server` class running and listening to a client. The client sends the `Server` object data. The `Server` then needs to send that data to a `Handler` object in the program. I have no prior experience with socket programming of any sort, so the only way I was able to achieve this was to give the `Server` class a reference to a data member in `Handler` and update the reference upon receiving data. That way, `Handler` will be updated whenever the client sends data. Here is trivialized code to show what I am currently doing:

```
while (connected)
{
    char recvbuf[258];
    int recvbuflen = sizeof(recvbuf);

    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);

    if (iResult > 0)
    {
        switch (recvbuf[0])
        {
            case 'h':
            {
                triggerEventReference = recvbuf[0];
                std::string str = std::string(recvbuf);
                str.erase(str.begin());
                str.resize(iResult - 1);
                strReference = str;
                break;
            }
            case 's':
                triggerEventReference = recvbuf[0];
                boundReference = recvbuf[1];
                otherReference = recvbuf[2];
                break;
            case 't':
                triggerEventReference = recvbuf[0];
                connected = 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

While this method certainly works, I feel like it's insecure and juvenile. Does anyone know of a better way to perform the same functionality?

Comment: Please include some relevant code. It is hard to offer any insights without any code.

Comment: Let the `Server` class have a reference to the `Handler` object, and simply call a member function in the `Handler` object passing the data?

Comment: @HanletEscaño Sorry, code has been added.